# How can I share methods and data between modules & classes?

Tags: python, class

I need some help regarding modules & class and how to share data and methods.

I have been working on a Python program for a while and it has gotten too big to deal with in its original form which did not use classes. The program is about 6000 lines long and uses [Tkinter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkinter) with multiple screens. I figured the logical breakdown into classes would follow the user interface with each screen being its own class. Then I would have another class that stores all the "global" data.

So far, with everything still in one file, and it is working.  However, I am now trying to break these classes out into separate modules by saving them in their own files.  This is where things got really bad for me.  I have read many tutorials and texts on classes and have seen a number of posts about my same problem here on Stack Overflow, but I still can't figure out what to do.

As my actual program is so big, I created a very simple program that shows what I need to do...

```
    #main.py


    class data:
        def __init__(self):
            self.A = "A"
            self.B = "B"
            self.C = "C"
            self.All = ""


    class module_1:
        def __init__(self):
            place_holder = "something"

        def add_1_2(self):
            d.All = d.A + d.B
            print("new_string=", d.All)


    class module_2:
        def __init__(self):
            place_holder = "something"

        def combine_it_all(self):
            m1.add_1_2()
            d.All = d.All + d.C



    d = data()
    m1 = module_1()
    m2 = module_2()

    m2.combine_it_all()
    print("d.All = ", d.All)
    print("END OF PROGRAM")
```

The program above shows how I want to access data in other classes and use their methods.  However, I also need to break out the program into modules so that they are much smaller and easier to work with. So, I tried to break out each class and put it in its own file (module) and now I don't know how to access data or methods in other classes which come from modules.  Here are the breakdowns of each file...

```
    #data_p.py

    class data:
        def __init__(self):
            self.A = "A"
            self.B = "B"
            self.C = "C"
            self.All = ""
```

```
    #module_1_p.py

    class module_1:
        def __init__(self):
            place_holder = "something"

        def add_1_2(self):
            d.All = d.A + d.B
            print("new_string=", d.All)
```

```
    #module_2_p.py

    class module_2:
        def __init__(self):
            place_holder = "something"

        def combine_it_all(self):
            m1.add_1_2()
            d.All = d.All + d.C
```

```
    #main.py

    from data_p import data
    from module_1_p import module_1
    from module_2_p import module_2

    d = data()
    m1 = module_1()
    m2 = module_2()

    m2.combine_it_all()
    print("d.All = ", d.All)
    print("END OF PROGRAM")
```

As you can see, there a problems with attributes and methods being addressed, but not yet instantiated.  Unfortunately, I am getting up there in years, and certainly not the brightest programmer around, but I am hoping someone can show me how to make this simple example work so that I can fix my actual program.

Comment: Avoid using `global d`, change to `def add_1_2(self, data):` and `data.All = data.A + data.B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is classes are instantiated, but each instance has no idea about the other, one way to fix it is to pass references in the method calls.
It's probably possible to do better in the actual context, but with these changes, your example will work:

```
#module_1_p.py (line 5 changed)

class module_1:
    def __init__(self):
        place_holder = "something"

    def add_1_2(self, d):
        d.All = d.A + d.B
        print("new_string=", d.All)


#module_2_p.py (lines 5 and 6 changed)

class module_2:
    def __init__(self):
        place_holder = "something"

    def combine_it_all(self, m1, d):
        m1.add_1_2(d)
        d.All = d.All + d.C

#main.py (line 9 changed)
from data_p import data
from module_1_p import module_1
from module_2_p import module_2

d = data()
m1 = module_1()
m2 = module_2()

m2.combine_it_all(m1, d)
print("d.All = ", d.All)
print("END OF PROGRAM")
```